# CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:323 (message): cl.exe (32-bit) and Visual Studio Generator (64-bit) do not match

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

It is my first time using cmake.

So I am writing in the developer command prompt for vs 2022

```
C:\Users\KBSI\OpenMS\JK_contrib>cmake -DBUILD_TYPE=ALL -DNUMBER_OF_JOBS=4 -G "Visual Studio 17 2022" -A x64 "C:\Users\KBSI\OpenMS\contrib"
```

> The result is below

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:323 (message):
  cl.exe (32-bit) and Visual Studio Generator (64-bit) do not match.  Please
  fix your PATH environment to find the proper cl.exe or use an appropriate
  generator by adding -A Win32/x64 to your CMake call.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/KBSI/OpenMS/JK_contrib/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

So I am adding .....X64/cl.exe to path environment also.

but it didn't work.

please help me.

---

Comment: Don't cmake in the developer command prompt for vs 2022.

Comment: I tested command `cmake -G "Visual Studio 17 2022" -A x64`in the developer command prompt for vs 2022. But did not occur your problem.

Comment: Did you restart command prompt after adding cl to path?

Comment: @273K Thank you for reply. However, Openms tutorial said that developer command prompt should be used. please refer to below link. https://abibuilder.cs.uni-tuebingen.de/archive/openms/Documentation/release/latest/html/install_win.html

Comment: @MinxinYu-MSFT thank you for your reply. I restart program. but it didnt't work.

Comment: The tutorial is incorrect. Cmake will find the proper cl.exe without a developer command prompt. In any case you run the 32 bit environment, try to run something like "Developer command prompt x64". And remove CMakeCache.txt after any environment changes.

Comment: Will it work when opened with command prompt?

Comment: @273K Thank you very much. I solved problem by following what you suggested (I used .X86_X64 cross tools command prompt instead of developer command prompt.) Thank you very much.

Comment: @MinxinYu-MSFT Yes. It can work when i used X86_X64 cross tools command prompt.

Comment: Glad to know you've  resolved this issue!

Comment: @273K  Consider converting comment to answer. Just a reminder :)

Comment: @MinxinYu-MSFT Thank you very much. I hope everything goes well for you.

Answer (score 0):

The project you're trying to build puts some restrictions on the environment you run the cmake configuration from along with mentioning the reason for this:

From [`OpenMS/contrib/CMakeLists.txt`](https://github.com/OpenMS/contrib/blob/4c3b1c48165055564f22e7330ff1b106b5345f69/CMakeLists.txt#L311)

```
  ...
  ## check that the console environment has a cl.exe architecture which is identical to the VS Generator
  ## If cl.exe builds 32-bit libs and VS Generator is Win64, we'd end up with mixed 32bit/64bit libraries, depending on how each lib is build (Cmake, bjam, nmake)
  execute_process(COMMAND "cl.exe" OUTPUT_VARIABLE cl_out ERROR_VARIABLE cl_out)
  ##message(STATUS "Cl.exe said: ${cl_out}")
  if (cl_out MATCHES ".*x64.*")
    message(STATUS "Cl.exe produces: 64-bit")
    set(CL_ADDRESSMODEL 64)
  elseif (cl_out MATCHES ".*x86.*")
    message(STATUS "Cl.exe produces: 32-bit")
    set(CL_ADDRESSMODEL 32)
  else()
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Could not determine if cl.exe builds x86 or x64 apps. Make sure cl.exe is available in your environment!")
  endif()
  if (NOT (CL_ADDRESSMODEL EQUAL CONTRIB_ADDRESSMODEL))
    message(FATAL_ERROR "cl.exe (${CL_ADDRESSMODEL}-bit) and Visual Studio Generator (${CONTRIB_ADDRESSMODEL}-bit) do not match. Please fix your PATH environment to find the proper cl.exe or use an appropriate generator by adding -A Win32/x64 to your CMake call.")
  endif()
  ...
```

`CONTRIB_ADDRESSMODEL` is set depending on the compiler properties as detected CMake ([`CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P.html)).

Note that here `cl.exe` is executed from the current process to detect the architecture of the program used. This program may be different to the compiler cmake chooses to use.

This requires you to make sure that both the compile chosen by cmake and `cl.exe` available in the command prompt both target x64 to set up the cmake project targeting x64. You'll need to run the correct `...\vcvarsall.bat x64` (or equivalent) before doing the cmake configuration.

Alternatively you need edit the `PATH` environment variable manually to list the directory containing the `cl.exe` targeting x64 before any other directories containing `cl.exe`s that target different architectures.

---

Note: I haven't taken a look closer look at why exactly this CMake logic was added, but it sounds like a terrible choice. Sure there are scenarios where you want to prevent building with an unexpected compiler, but there are CMake generators hardcoding the absolute paths to programs like the compiler and working with those is hindered by putting such a restriction in place...

Comment: Thank you very much for your much efforts. I read carefully what you wrote. Because i am a newbie to computer field, I cannot how to do "run the correct...\vcvarsall.bat x64..." . And I edited the path environment it didn't work.

Comment: I solved the problem what @273K suggested. However, I am very impressed by your answer. Thank you very much again.